# iPad: MFMailComposeViewController crashes with attachments

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

My app includes a form where a user selects a number of PDF files which are then attached to an email. All of the PDF files are relatively small, between 250 KB and 1.0 MB, but the entire app crashes consistently if I attach more than 4 of them on an iPad 3 (attaching one or two seems to be fine). It doesn't crash in the Simulator.

This is running with iOS 5.1 using ARC, so there shouldn't be a leak. When I profile it with Allocations using Instruments the Overall Bytes goes from 9.3 MB to 22.4 MB, which is certainly a spike but I wouldn't think that would cause a crash.

Here is my code:

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
  MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
  mail.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
  mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
  [mail setSubject:subject];
  [mail setMessageBody:body isHTML:NO];

  for (NSString *document in documents) {
    @autoreleasepool {
      NSError *error;
      NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:document ofType:@"pdf"] options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&error];
      if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error loading document %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
      }
      [mail addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:document];
      data = nil;
    }
  }

  [self presentModalViewController:mail animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: "Crashes" is very vague.  What happens?  Can you post the traceback?